# Reset JSF form fields

Tags: forms, jsf

I know a lot has been going around this topic, but all the solutions point out to creating a reset button ... is there no way of just clearing the fields and re-populating them ?

Here is what is my code

```
<p:commandButton id="basic" value="#{c.machine}" action="#{updateEntry.setMachine(c.machine)}" oncomplete="dlg1.show();" styleClass="ui-Machinebutton"/>
```

This sets the value 'machine' in 'updateEntry' and once completed launches the dialog box 'dlg1'

**Dialog Box**

```
<p:dialog id="Update_Entry" header="Update Entry" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="250" dynamic="True" resizable="False">  
                    <h:form prependId="false" id="Update_Entry_Form" method="post" autocomplete="off">  

                            <h:panelGrid id="update_grid" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px"> 

                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    <p:messages />  
                                </f:facet> 
                                <h:outputLabel for="machine" value="Machine *" />  
                                <p:inputText id="machine" value="#{updateEntry.machine}" required="true" requiredMessage="Machine is required">
                                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="5"/>
                                </p:inputText>
```

The form loads the value fine for the first time, but it always loads the previous value even if updateEntry.machine is updated. How do i clear this off automatically ? I am using PrimeFaces

Comment: Clear the values in the managed bean.

Comment: Once dialog is updated, update the dialog dom tree on your action, update=":update_grid", Also if you are not interested in letting them see the updated value, u can always change scope of bean to requestScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to ajax-update the dialog's content before opening. That's why it's always showing initial content as it was when the page was rendered for the first time or when the dialog was closed for the last time.

Do so accordingly:

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":Update_Entry">
```

Comment: Thanks ! That worked, althought the ajax update needs to be done in the <p:commandButton ...>

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use my brains while entering the answer. Fixed it.